# Does Singapore have an electronics district something like Tokyo's Akihabara?

Tags: electronic-items, shopping, singapore

In a few weeks I expect to be flying into Singapore to start a long overland trip. But my current laptop is dying and I like to have one on my travels.

So I'm pretty sure computers and electronics will be much cheaper in Singapore than here at home in Australia.

What I am wondering though is whether Singapore has an area dedicated to hi-tech... something similar to [Akihabara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akihabara) in Tokyo where all kinds of nerdy gadgets new and used can be found.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not the same scale, but generally people head to two particular shopping centres: [Funan DigitalLife Mall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funan_DigitaLife_Mall) & [Sim Lim Square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sim_Lim_Square).

[image: View inside Sim Lim Square]
<sup>View inside Sim Lim Square by hippietrail</sup>

Funan is more upmarket than Sim Lim, which caters more to the general populous.

The downside is that there are quite a few ongoing scams at some of the stores in these centres.  Some of these are described in the second link. So you have to come prepared, having done your research, and know what you should be expecting when you buy something, how much it should cost and what it should do.

Comment: Otherwise you're spot on, but I'd reverse the characterizations: Funan IT sells "normal" electronics/computer gear and is where I'd tell my parents go buy a camera or a mouse, whereas Sim Lim has a lot more very specialist shops geared towards the hardcore geek who knows exactly what he wants.

Comment: @jpatokal Interesting. I couldn't actually remember which of the two was which, so I added in that description as paraphrased from the first Wiki link. Maybe it depends on which shops you go to? :/

Comment: I'll be looking for a netbook around the $300 range - now a dying breed so I'm not sure whether I would need a mainstream or geeky place ...

Comment: Best try both then ;)  I was playing with an Asus T600 today (transforming tablet) - it's actually really nice.  But I can't deal with Win 8.

Comment: You need to be more careful if you want to buy stuff in Sim Lim Square. Some of shop owners cheat from the customers. If possible, always go to Funan. You can check some of the case in http://www.case.org.sg Read the news here : http://sg.entertainment.yahoo.com/blogs/going-out-by-day/sim-lim-cheating-vendors-named-shamed-080508598.html